# Map TRttiProperty to a class definition equivalent

Tags: delphi, reflection, properties, delphi-xe, rtti

I'm wondering if its possible to reference a class definition directly for purpose of using it in conjunction to RTTI (map a property to TRttiProperty, etc).

E.g.

I would like to use TMyClass.MyProperty as a TRttiProperty, without having to resolve it via a name/ string, this will keep my code and compiler integrity intact, as string variables may be misspelled, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming which you want do something like this

```
 P:=TRttiProperty(TMyClass.MyProperty);
```

or write  a function like so

```
function GetPropertyInfo(P: reference to property):TRttiProperty;
```

This is not possible, to do this possible you will require which delphi has support to property references. So the only current way to access (reference) an class property is using his name via an string.

Comment: Thanks, too bad though, i was hoping for an undocumented feature.